# How to clone a content type and all nodes related

Tags: commerce, ubercart

My site is using Ubercart, so now I want to use Commerce module instead, the problem now is Product content type, when I turn off all Ubercart modules, Product content type will be disabled.

I have more than 1000 nodes (Product content type), so now how to clone Product content type and moving all nodes to new content type?

Thank so much.

Comment: Not to complicate things, but it's probably better that you know this in advance if you don't already - Drupal Commerce has its own entity type (commerce_product) which stores things like the sku, price, stock info, etc, and it uses nodes to display those products via an entity reference field. Cloning the content type and moving the nodes over to the new type will certainly work as an exercise, but it won't automagically make your site compatible with Commerce

Answer (score 1):

Drupal commerce stores product in a different way than ubercart. You best bet would be to export product in CSV format using something like [Views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) and reimport it to Drupal commerce using [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) and [Commerce feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_feeds)